# Refresh Only One Worksheet of Bloomberg Data With VBA

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I need to refresh only one worksheet of Bloomberg data with VBA.
If I try with:

```
Application.Run "RefreshAllWorkbooks"
Application.Run "RefreshAllStaticData"
```

it will refresh all the Workbook.

Do you know how to refresh only one worksheet?

Thanks.

Comment: You can refresh the relevant connection/query only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a few query tables in a give worksheet, the easiest way to refresh each of them is to create a for-loop. This would refresh all the objects in the first worksheet of Excel:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim jLo As ListObject
    For Each jLo In Worksheets(1).ListObjects
        jLo.QueryTable.Refresh
    Next jLo

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorksheet"
```

or

```
Private Sub refreshBBG(xlWsName As String)
If Not Sheets(xlWsName) Is Nothing Then
    Sheets(xlWsName).Activate
    Application.Run "RefreshEntireWorksheet"
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh
```

The following will also work:

```
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
ThisWorkbook.Connections("Query - MYQUERYNAME").OLEDBConnection.Refresh
```